# Is there a suggesting edits mode on Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

My supervisor wants to suggest edits in Latex file in Overleaf edits. So I could keep track of his changes and his comments. How could that be easily done in Overleaf?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try asking Overleaf directly?

Comment: Perhaps have a look at https://www.overleaf.com/blog/176-rich-commenting-is-here-manage-your-feedback-and-review-on-writelatex-number-backtoschool or https://www.overleaf.com/blog/298-rejecting-changes-how-to-revert-a-chunk-on-overleaf ; or if you'd like to use LaTeX packages, https://www.overleaf.com/help/41-can-i-add-inline-or-margin-comments-to-the-pdf or https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/tracking-changes-in-latex-with-changes-package/fnpkpytjjwhj . And as egreg suggested, you can contact support@overleaf.com for more details.

Comment: I have the same question!

Comment: btw, is overleaf safe to use? I mean, I always have this feeling that they're looking at my work :-)

Comment: If it's in the cloud, you should assume other people are looking at it.  OTOH, my opinion is that most people overestimate how snoop worthy their work actually is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is built into Overleaf now, though it might not have been at the time of the question being asked. You can now add comments and track changes in real time, however it may require a paid subscription.

[image]

Comment: Better late than never! Thanks for your comment.